# Change view on button click from CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have created a layout that contains a listView, the view is populated with multiple similar elements in the onCreateView function from a Fragment, the view is populated in the CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter. In each element of the listView I have a button for which I want to implement a onClickListener. When the button is clicked I want to switch to another view, something similar to viewing comments on the GooglePlus mobile app. 
I have tried doing so this way in the CustomAdapter:

```
public void setOnClickComment(View view) {

        final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.addComment);
        if (btn != null) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("ONCLICK", "I just clicked this shit" + btn.getTag());
                    manager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.feedLayout, new CommentFragment()).commit();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("CLICK", "ESTE NULL");
        }
    }
```

The manager is a FragmentManager and it's passed from the fragment to the CustomAdapter constructor. I can see the Log in LogCat but that's it nothing else happens, the tag of the button is the position of the element.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/feedLayout"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the fragment I inflate the above layout:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_screen_left, container, false);
        view = (ListView) linear.getChildAt(0);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), data, getFragmentManager());
        view.setAdapter(adapter);

       return linear;
    }
```

Comment: Is `R.id.feedLayout`visible on the current layout?

Comment: Try adding the fragment to the backstack on the transaction and after your commit try doing `manager.executePendingTransactions();`

Comment: I did this:      FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.feedLayout, new CommentFragment()); 
     trans.addToBackStack(null);
     trans.commit();  but it still doesn't work